# Error when build Android project with '--incompatible_disable_native_android_rules'

Tags: android, bazel

When I try to build my project with `--incompatible_disable_native_android_rules`, I got next error:

```
ERROR: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/aee0be3e153556afb3ddc0b7aea89213
/external/androidsdk/BUILD.bazel:8:1: in tags attribute of android_sdk 
rule @androidsdk//:sdk-28: The native Android rules are deprecated. 
Please use the Starlark Android rules by adding the following load statement 
to the BUILD file: load("@build_bazel_rules_android//android:rules.bzl",
"android_sdk"). See http://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android.. 
Since this rule was created by the macro 'create_android_sdk_rules', 
the error might have been caused by the macro implementation in
/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/aee0be3e153556afb3ddc0b7aea89213/
external/androidsdk/BUILD.bazel:8:1
```

.

After Bazel 0.27 installing I use

```
load("@rules_android//android:rules.bzl", android_sdk_repository_rule = "android_sdk_repository")
...
def my_sdk_rule(name = None, api_level = None, build_tools_version = None):    
    android_sdk_repository_rule(
        name = name,
        api_level = api_level,
        build_tools_version = build_tools_version,
    )
```

as described in https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8391.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `android_sdk_repository` workspace rule generates native `android_sdk` rules:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/ebfd3bcb0baec0774db584fd3ff5445a1ec7925b/tools/android/android_sdk_repository_template.bzl#L107

See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8757 for updates.